# angular4 click doesn't work on div with ngIf

Tags: html, css, angular

I'm trying to  add click event to div. this div contains another div that is generated by ngIf on Boolean that I get as input.
in this case, the event is not working, only on the border of the outer div.
here is the html:

```
<div class="cell-content-wrapper" (mouseover)="over()" (mouseout)="out()"     (click)="openModal()">
  <div  *ngIf="myInput" class="cell-content" [ngClass]="[cell.action]">
    <span class="tf {{ (cell.action | actionToIcon) }} cell-icon"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

and this is the component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'usp-cell',
  templateUrl: './usp-cell.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./usp-cell.component.scss']
})
export class UspCellComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {

  @Input() cell:;
  @Input() myInput: boolean;
  @Output() onClick: EventEmitter<UspCell> = new EventEmitter<>();
  @Output() onMouseOver: EventEmitter<UspCell> = new EventEmitter<>();
  @Output() onMouseOut: EventEmitter<UspCell> = new EventEmitter<>();

  over() {
    this.onMouseOver.emit(this.cell);
  }

  out() {
    this.onMouseOut.emit(this.cell);
  }
  openModal() {
   this.onClick.emit(this.cell);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to define custom event emitters for mouse-related DOM events.

Users of your component can handle click, mouseover, or mouseout events:

HTML

```
<usp-cell (click)="onClick($event)" 
     (mouseover)="onMouseOver($event)" 
     (mouseout)="onMouseOut($event)"></usp-cell>
```

If you want the component `usp-cell` to handle the event because it needs to do something, then you can use `@HostListener`

```
@HostListener('click', ['$event.target']) onClick(cell) {
   ...
}
```

Comment: thanks for your quick answer but it doesn't help.
it looks like the inner div (that is generated by ngIf) is blocking the click
the click event is thrown only if I click on the oouter div's border

Comment: @user3800293 - then your DOM architecture is not well designed. The brutforce approach to your problem is to block mouseevents on the parent and allow them on child. You can do it by css. At parent, use pointer-events: none and on child use pointer-events: all ...

Comment: @Emocuc I understand that my architecture has a problem but don't understand how to fix it.
I have a div that contains some other elements. the content is different  if the mouse is down or up. I need all the div to be clickable. how can I implement it?

Comment: @user3800293 - it is good to think about the app in ahead of coding, creating wireframes, use cases, graphic mockups ... and based on the overall app features decide how the app will be coded ... from you snippet or comment, I cannot provide you any suggestion, I guess you have to learn it the hard way ...

Answer (score 0):

The HTML element events work bubbling, this means they are propagated from children to parents, but not in the other way. So if your parent div has the event the children will not have it. Check this example:

```
<div (click)="test()" style="background-color: #b30000; height: 150px">
  <div style="background-color: #00CC9B; height: 10px">
  </div>
</div>
```

In this case only the parent div will call test function despite the fact the other one is contained inside it.

Comment: I didn't know it. how can I give them the event?

Answer (score 0):

found the problem , even I don't understand it well.
the boolean was change according to mouseDown event. if the mouse is down so div a should appear, else, div B will appear. so when I clicked there were two different elements. here is the fix

```
<div class="cell-content-wrapper" (mouseover)="over()" (mouseout)="out()" (click)="openModal()">
 <div class="cell-content" [ngClass]="[cell.action]">

<div *ngIf="myInput" ....>
  ....
</div>

<div *ngIf="!myInput" ....>
  ....
</div>

</div>
</div>
```